# Permission denied install pyforest notebook extension

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I have installed pyforest with :

```
pip install --upgrade pyforest
```

It worked well, but when I run on terminal :

```
python -m pyforest install_extensions
```

I have this output :

```
Starting to install pyforest extensions for Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab

Trying to install pyforest nbextension...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bled/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"main", mod_spec)
File "/home/bled/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/bled/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyforest/main.py", line 15, in
install_extensions()
File "/home/bled/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyforest/utils.py", line 19, in install_extensions
install_nbextension()
File "/home/bled/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyforest/utils.py", line 38, in install_nbextension
nbextensions.install_nbextension_python("pyforest")
File "/home/bled/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 225, in install_nbextension_python
destination=dest, logger=logger
File "/home/bled/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 126, in install_nbextension
ensure_dir_exists(nbext)
File "/home/bled/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/utils/init.py", line 13, in ensure_dir_exists
os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
File "/home/bled/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
File "/home/bled/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter'
```

I have tried :

```
python -m pyforest install_extensions --user
```

But it doesn't work either and instead gives the following output:

> Usage: python -m pyforest install_extensions installs notebook/lab
>   extensions

Can somone please help?

Answer (score 0):

'python -m pyforest install_extensions' run this command on anaconda prompt not on terminal. There is another way we can install the extensions directly from jupyter notebook. These are the commands to follow

```
import pyforest
pyforest.install_nbextension()
pyforest.install_labextension()
```

Comment: There is still a permissions issue.